# Make adjective apply to two different places in a sentence

Tags: adjectives, redundancy, paraphrasing

> The minster must report to the head of the **pertinent** central administrative agency and the head of the **pertinent** local government.

Here, I want to apply the adjective 'pertinent' to both 'central administrative agency' and 'local government'. Is saying 'pertinent' two times the normal way to go? Could I just mention 'pertinent' once (or is that more desirable)?

As a side question, would you include 'to' (as shown below) or just leave it out for being wordy?:

> The minster must report to the head of the **pertinent** central administrative agency and **to** the head of the **pertinent** local government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unnecessary to repeat the words pertinent and to in the sentence presented.  You can rephrase it as follows:

The minister must report to the heads of the pertinent central administrative agency and the local government.